# After the first loop run, i get stuck at the default case inside the switch

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

1.For some reason i get stuck at the default case after the first loop run, does not matter what I input 'y' or 'n'.

```
    while(edit==1){

        option='\0';
        printf("Would you like to edit?(y or n)\n");
        scanf("%c",&option);
        getchar();

          // getchar() so if forces scanf()

        switch(option){

            // first run is flawless

            case 'y':
                printf("What would like to edit?\n");
                printf("1)Edit an entire line.\n");
                printf("2)Edit a substring of a line.\n");

                scanf("%c",&option);

                if(option=='1'){

                } else if(option =='2'){

                    printf("What word to change :");
                    scanf("%s",toFind);

                    printf("What would to change \"%s\" to :", toFind);
                    scanf("%s",replaceWith);

                    printf("which line to search :");
                    scanf("%d",&line);

                    replaceInString(buffer[line], toFind, replaceWith);
                    printBuffer(buffer);

                } else printf("Invalid input!!!\nTry again\n");
                edit=1;
                break;

            case 'n':
                edit=0;
                printBuffer(buffer);
                break;

            default:
                printf("Invalid input!!!\nTry again\n");
                // first run is fine then i get stuck here.
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you reach this page, my fix was change the first scanf from `scanf("%c",&option)` to `scanf("  %c",&option)`. I added a space before `  %c`

Answer (score 0):

When you are reading a character using scanf - you will input y and press . y will be assigned to option (ie option - Y) and  will be in buffer. when you call scanf next time  present in the buffer will be assigned to option hence goes to the default case.
to avoid this leave a space before %c in scanf. this does not happen in case of integers or float.